# How can a Malign Government Dispose of "Lone Wolves" / Survivalist Communities Following a Doomsday Scenario?

Tags: society, government, apocalypse

**Premise**

Faced with growing concerns of limited resources, a malign government has purposefully engaged in several ways to depopulate their country. Martial law was instated, food supplies were cut off, public services were discontinued, bio-epidemics were set loose, ect. After a month, roughly 85% of the population was successfully "exterminated". At this point, the powerful officials reclining in their arm-chairs in their secret underground bunker facilities began to assess the situation.

They discovered that throughout the country, there were small pockets of survival enthusiast communities who were living far from urban centers. These survival enthusiasts have been preparing in advance for years (considered paranoid by others during times of peace). They have improvised bunkers made of shipping containers, hoards of medical supplies and chemical suits. They also have off-grid survival techniques, and a close-knit network of trusted members who were always very weary of big brother.

There were also reports of "lone wolves". These were former military personnel or other individuals with advanced tactical training. "Lone wolves" posed a moderate threat as well, because they know how to go "gray" (hide in plain sight) as well as improvise and operate many weapons. The chain of command wants both of these surviving civilian groups disposed of.

**Question**

How would a malign government set about disposing rural survivalist communities who have mini-bunkers and hoards of survival oriented items (water filtration, gas masks, green houses)? Similarly, how could the government dispose of the "lone wolves" who possess field-craft skills and are adept at becoming "gray".

**Further Clarification**

- **Development Index:** Highly Developed Country, high standard of living
- **Geographic Area:** very large, several million sq miles
- **Government Resources:** moderate; needs to be resourceful as many of the supply chains were sacrificed for the depopulation event
- **Success Metric:** 99% or higher civilian mortality rate if in one fell swoop, or 100% if plan is related to long-term attrition
- **Time Frame:** Either short or long term solutions are acceptable, but include a general time line if you can
- **Military Status:** Existent, but short on manpower. Only a few elite teams remain; your average G.I. Joe wasn't on the salvation
  list

Comment: This is... an uncomfortable question, being related to a survivalist wounded warrior. Can you clarify what you mean by going gray?

Comment: I find the idea of a development index in this kind of setting very interesting. It might be important for the answer: Why do they want to dispose of those people, especially given the size and density, and why is a military solution not an option?

Comment: How did these people escape the bio-epidemic in the first place?

Comment: If it's specialized military lingo, you may want to edit that into your question - I couldn't find a reference to that particular use of the term.

Comment: @Fhnuzoag Not very many did, key phrase is "survival enthusiast" people who have shipping container bunkers in the back yard and gas masks for that rainy day. I'll try to clarify in the post.

Comment: Sure but I don't see how that actually helps. It's not like a 'rainy day' sort of thing.

Comment: If you're trying to kill off everyone, how can a soldier "go gray?" You would shoot them anyhow, since you're trying to kill everyone...

Comment: Like the obvious answer to this is 'do the bio-epidemic thing again, but do it properly this time'. Look up Operation Vegetarian, only this time with say a tailored bioagent that can stay latent in the environment for long period. The only puzzle is why there were survivors in the first round.

Comment: @Fhnuzoag That can be an option, but presumably part of the survival enthusiasts' bag of tricks is improvised quarantine procedures. And they don't live in densely populated areas, making it hard for the contagion to spread. Also bear in mind there are limited government resources, as they have killed off their tax churning source.

Comment: Are we assuming these survivalist communities don't have much daily contact amongst the members of these communities and don't share food/water sources and have advanced methods to diagnose infections? Because historically these communities actually do worse than average in major pandemics.

Comment: @Fhnuzoag You could make that assumption, and also you bring up a good point. It's their supplies and expertise that would be their saving grace, not being rural.

Comment: I'm saying the question is very badly misspecified. These survivors clearly need something special to survive the initial assault, or the evil government badguys need very tight restrictions to not have gone after these guys in ways that are pretty obvious, in the initial wave.

Comment: Cheapest solution - BURN EVERYTHING. What is the goal in killing everyone?

Comment: are the numbers of survivors sufficiently high to actually challenge the government?  Otherwise, the risk they pose is as individuals.   They can be picked off one by one as they come out of their secure bunkers.  Why waste the resources tracking them?

Comment: @ECiurleo The exact number is left ambiguous. Though we could infer that the malign government would have no accurate way to get telemetry anymore. Meaning they don't know exactly who / how many they could potentially be facing. Arguably, having a shadowy enemy would create a certain amount of fear.

Comment: or a common enemy they can "protect against" :)

Comment: Not getting the downvotes on this one.  It may need a little clarification, as to the motives of the government for destroying the population, but the bones of something interesting are there.

Comment: @PaulTIKI I wondered too, but it does seem a lot like a "what should I write?" question, which is out of scope here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, It's pretty clear your government has no compunction about killing people, so all you have to do is find them.

Even the best preppers are not going going to be able to fortify their position well enough to stop something like a massive tank assault and multiple airstikes. I mention Tanks and Airstrikes becasue those are going to cause the greatest amount of damage for the lowest amount of manpower. Massive overkill will work, once you find the enclave.

finding the Enclave becomes the trick, in this instance.

As for your lone wolf guys, you are probably just going to have to ignore them and play damage control when they turn up and cause trouble.  Each action they take is going to leave another little stub of evidence to allow you to track them down, eventually.  As long as they don't cause trouble, they stop being a problem.  Instill in you survivors that you want to keep around a massive level of paranoia to help with catching them, but I think it's unlikely for you to have a 100% success rate against highly trained individuals.  All they have to do to drop off your map is to do nothing, or go out into the woods and hide.  If they aren't interacting with people you don't get a trail to work with.

So find the enclaves and hit with massive overkill.  Play damage control with your lone wolves is going to be the best course of action.

If you already have intel on the bulk of the prepper enclaves, this won't take long to overwhelm them. the faster you move, the better. so call it a year to wipe the known prepper enclaves. This will give you time for maintenance on your hardware with more limited crews.  After your year is up though, entropy on your equipment is going to start getting the better of you.

Lone wolf types, lets face it, you aren't going to get all of them...ever.  they are too small of a target, and not worth the concerted effort to bring them all down unless they really start to cause trouble.  Causing trouble leaves traces, that can be followed.

The biggest problem you have is that you have killed off way too many people.  You left enough that you can function for a while, but entropy is going to take over, and it will accelerate.  Your government is ultimately suicidal.

Comment: I don't know how this government could even realistically function. Will whoever is left even listen to them? Why would they? They would have to be forced via military means. And why would a military even listen to this government? Besides being crazy destructive, even if the military was bribed through promises of a better life, why not just throw a coup after? After all, the biggest thing stopping a coup is rule of law.  Which just went out the window through the government's purge of its own citizens.

Comment: @user2259716 The thing is the government wouldn't really function for long, but they would hang on to power, at least for a while through lies, and when the lies stop working, fear and violence.  Either way, it's still ultimately suicidal

Answer (score 9):

Quantum teleportation of cyberviruses into their bodies, keyed to True Names in the language of Mu.
The scenario is not internally consistent. Therefore, if you want to include specific imagery in a story (sentient molecules, gnomes riding bees, the Moon crashing into the Earth because of a Facebook post), you can just go ahead and write them in.

Comment: That opening sentence....what a glorious collection of words.

Answer (score 6):

1) Admit that footage from Moon landing was fake, while actually it is covered with nice temperate forest.

2) Officially ban Julius Verne book From the Earth to the Moon.

3) Make clear that is banned.

4) Leak plans of big guns to launch people on the Moon. Any scientific accuracy is unnecessary, but to look credible they should have written key words "TOP SECRET" and "HAARP".

5) Officially make escaping from Earth to Moon a very serious criminal offence.

6) If they still don't get the bait, officially deny rumors that hundreds of people already escaped this way.

Answer (score 5):

## Make America Great Britain Again

There's no point hunting them down. They'll die soon enough anyway. As soon as you've killed off most of your population the next country over will invade what's left.

If they don't invade you'll probably find your survivalists were all men so there won't be another generation. If they were not all men the women will probably die in childbirth.

Comment: Not to mention that there is absolutely no need to hunt them down. If the purge was done for resource reasons, these survivors will not be living in a "developed" country and therefore will not be consuming many resources. Besides that, many of those preppers are not truly prepared, will typically be isolated, or just run out of supplies. There is a difference between having a year's worth of food and knowing how to get more once it is gone. Accidents, murder, insanity and suicides will spike quickly among them.